# CSS hover dropdown menu, position absolute?

Tags: html, wordpress, css

The best way to describe this issue is with pictures (Don't mind the Dutch), I'm stuck with this at the moment:
[Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTivo.png)

In the first example you can see that the red dropdown hover lines with the parent in this case. What I want is this:
[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hidwt.png)

The way I did it in Example2 was with element inspect and changing the Ul's manually with margin-top (40px). Which means I have to do 80px, 120px etc. On the next couple of menu links.

Is there an easier way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet

Comment: To improve the quality of your Question, please post enough enough of the code in your files for us to be able to replicate (and fix) the problem.

Comment: Try giving the content-area `position: relative;` and then placing the dropdown inside this container and position it `absolute` with `top: 0` and `left: 0`. This might look awkward for menus lower down though.

Answer (score 2):

Position the dropdown menu relative to the menu container (`<ul>`) instead of the menu item (`<li>`).

A simple example on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andreasvirkus/88pwmctr/25/).

The relative HTML:

```
<ul class="outer">
  <li>
    Beelden

    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Geurkaarsen</li>
      <li>Rituele kaarsen</li>
      <li>Affirmatie kaarsen</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
/* Your outer menu */
ul.outer {
  position: relative;
}

li {
  /* Whatever styles you set here, don't give it relative positioning */
}

ul.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Live demo:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body > ul {
  /* This next line is crucial */
  position: relative;
  background-color: #c5e2d8;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}

ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
}

li {
  display: block;
  color: #444;
  padding: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

  li.has-children::after {
    content: '▸';
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
  }
  
  li:hover {
    background-color: tomato;
  }
  
  li.has-children:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="has-children">
    Beelden
    
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Geurkaarsen</li>
      <li>Rituele kaarsen</li>
      <li>Affirmatie kaarsen</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children">
    Kaarsen
    
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Sub-menu 2</li>
      <li>I don't know</li>
      <li>any Dutch</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Wierook</li>
  <li>Kruiden</li>
  <li>Olien</li>
</ul>
```